# Handling multiple bash threads with python script?

Tags: python, bash

I want to have a python script that simulates a user having 3 open terminal windows, and calling commands on each of them in parallel. I envision it as something like:

```
cmd1 = Bash()
cmd1.call('cd python')
cmd2 = Bash()
cmd2.call('cd haskell')
cmd3 = Bash()
cmd3.call('cd rust')
for question in range(5):
   output1 = cmd1.call('python {}'.format(question))
   output2 = cmd1.call('./{}'.format(question))
   output3 = cmd1.call('./{}'.format(question))
   [format output and print stuff]
```

so the base python script is acting as a kind of supervisor. I'm open to using a better tool for this task.

Comment: Ideally I want more sophistication that just calling scripts, like interacting with a running python script within one of the threads. But just a basic call would do too for the meantime.

Comment: Do you want literally open three GUI windows or is it enough to pipe commands to three bash processes? Unless `output` is a Future-like object; the calls won't be in parallel. How do you know when to stop reading output from a command (some commands may continue to print even if the immediate child has finished (the shell prompt is shown)?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? This can be done -- I'd use `pexpect`, personally -- but it's highly error-prone (if a command being run emits content that looks like a shell prompt, there's no completely unambiguous way to distinguish whether the prior command is done), and is probably adding a great deal of incidental complexity to whatever you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Keep in mind that only specific kinds of shell commands can modify the parent shell's working directory, environment, or other state -- invocation of a fully external process necessarily leaves the shell back in the position it was in when it started, so you gain nothing at all by using a real shell session to run those, vs simply spawning them independently with working directory and environment variables persistently maintained if you have a reason to update them mid-script.

Comment: you could do some interesting things using a terminal multiplexer such as `screen`, `tmux` but whether the additional complexity is justified depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I do not need a GUI at all.

Answer (score 0):

Version for Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from select     import select
from time       import sleep
from os         import read
cmd1 = Popen('bash', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, cwd='python')
cmd2 = Popen('bash', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, cwd='haskell')
cmd3 = Popen('bash', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, cwd='rust')
def gather_output(rlist, output):
    for reads in iter(lambda: select(rlist, [], [], 0)[0], []):
        for ready in reads:
            output[rlist.index(ready)] += read(ready.fileno(), 4096)
for question in range(5):
    cmd1.stdin.write('python {0}\n'.format(question))
    cmd2.stdin.write(     './{0}\n'.format(question))
    cmd3.stdin.write(     './{0}\n'.format(question))
cmdo = [cmd1.stdout, cmd2.stdout, cmd3.stdout]
output = [""]*len(cmdo)
while not output[2]:
    sleep(.1)
    gather_output(cmdo, output)
print 1, '\n', output[0]
print 2, '\n', output[1]
print 3, '\n', output[2]
```

The function `gather_output(rlist, output)` is essential for the task. It reads the command output which is *already* available from the pipes in `rlist` and catenates it to the corresponding `output[]` string. It does not block, so it can be called at any time that seems appropriate for the application, on which it depends (as J.F. Sebastian hinted at in his comment above) when to stop reading output - that may be after a certain time, or when a certain string occurs in the output. In the example here I haphazardly chose to gather output from the commands until some output from the third command appeared. Note regarding the use of `os.read()`: This works better here than the often seen read() or readline() methods of a “file object” - `readline()` doesn't work with non-terminated lines, and `read(1)` may be quite inefficient, issuing one read() call on the underlying pipe for every single output byte. Finally, due to the use of `select` with pipes, this works only on a sane OS, not on Windows.

Changes for Python 3:

```
            output[rlist.index(ready)] += read(ready.fileno(), 4096).decode()
...
    cmd1.stdin.write('python {0}\n'.format(question).encode())
    cmd2.stdin.write(     './{0}\n'.format(question).encode())
    cmd3.stdin.write(     './{0}\n'.format(question).encode())
...
print(1, output[0], sep='\n')
print(2, output[1], sep='\n')
print(3, output[2], sep='\n')
```